# Optimization problem: Mongoose aggregate() doesn't return Model objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-schema

I use a Model that, simplifying a lot, has some custom functions such as:

```
let MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  firstName: {type: String},
  lastName: {type: String},
  status: {type: String}
})

// Model custom functions
MySchema = {
  login(email, callback) {...},
  logout(email, callback) {...},
  ...
}

// This works
MySchema.findOne({email: userId}).then(user => user.loging())

// This also works
let user = await MySchema.findOne({email: userId})
user.logout()
```

... apply AppUsers as mongoose model of such Schema

```
// This works
let users = await AppUser.aggregate([
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "stg_appusers",
            "localField": "email",
            "foreignField": "email",
            "as": "stg"
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "stg.email": {
              "$exists": false
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            status: "expired"
          }
        }
      ]).exec()

// At this point the aggregate() returns correctly what
// I need from the query (difference but two collections)
// as array, but each element of the array is not a Model
// for which I can invoke my Model custom functions
users.forEach(user => {
  user.logout() // ⚠️ This doesn't work: TypeError: user.lgout is not a function
})

// I am using following as workaround...
users.forEach(user => {
  AppUsers.findOne({email: user.email}).then(userFetched => userFetched.logout()) // This works, but...
})
```

Overall, the code is working by using `AppUser.findOne({email: user.email}).then(userFetched => userFetched.logout())` but clearly is not performant: after the `aggregate()` I am not able to use the `logout()` function, so I have to call a `find()` for each user returned from the `aggregate()`.

Calling `findOne()` for each user found by the `aggregate()` would be fine, but the two Collections have similarly more than 1.000.000 users and the findOne() takes too time.

Why I can't call `users := user.logout()` where users is the result of the `aggregate()`?

---

Update from comment:

```
[
  {
    _id: 6040fd38191f66368dfe4ca0,
    status: 'active',
    email: 'some.one@coolcompany.com',
    firstName: 'some',
    lastName: 'one',
    ... many other fields, such as in the findOne()
  }
]
```

Comment: can u update sample of `users` of aggregate ?

Comment: does it has a `logout()` method as property ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am supposing that the output of aggregate() is unlike a Model.find() or similar action since the purpose here is to "reshape the results".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399775/mongoose-populate-after-aggregate